# Examples of Noetherian local rings which are not Gorenstein

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, noetherian, injective-module, gorenstein

Can anyone give me an example of a Noetherian local ring which is not a Gorenstein ring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Gorenstein local ring is Cohen-Macaulay and of type $1$ [see Proposition 3.2.10 of Bruns and Herzog *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*]. So if, (1) a ring is not CM or (2) the type of a ring is not $1$, then that ring will not be Gorenstein. Therefore you have plenty of examples, such as:
$k[x,y,z]/(x) \cap (y,z)$,
$k[x,y,u,v]/(x,y)\cap (u,v)$,
2.1.18 in Bruns and Herzog,
2.1.19 in Bruns and Herzog.
(which are not CM).

AND

you can use the *type* to reach other examples; such as *Matt E*'s example.
Also example 3.2.11(a) of Bruns and Herzog have other examples.

Comment: for good equivalent conditions of  Gorenstein local rings see theorem 18.1 of the book "Commutative ring theory" (by MATSUMURA)

Comment: But $k[x,y,z]/(x) \cap (y,z)$ is not a local ring since $(x,y,z) , (x-1,y,z)$ are different two maximal ideals.

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  The ring $k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ (here $k$ is a field) is not Gorenstein.

Comment: Could you please justify why your example works?

Comment: @JorgeAntónio: There are several ways to explain. For instance, one can say the type is $2$ or the Hilbert function is not Symmetric. It may be helpful if you can list equivalent definitions you already know.

Comment: @JorgeAntónio: Dear Jorge, As Youngsu says, take more-or-less any definition of Gorenstein and apply it in this case, and you will see this ring is not Gorenstein.  What definition are you most comfortable with?  Regards,

Comment: I am only familiar with the definition of Gorenstein rings concerning injective dimension.

Comment: @JorgeAntónio: Do you know the fact that if a Noetherian local ring has finite injective dimension, then that injective dimension is equal to the depth of the ring? Given this, it suffices to show that this ring is not injective, which can be done by Baer's criterion

Comment: Dear zcn, I know such fact, however I am afraid that I do not understand your last sentence. Why should I look to the injectivity of this ring?

Comment: @JorgeAntónio: Dear Jorge, If this ring is Gorenstein, then zcn's comment shows that it has injective dimension zero, hence is injective over itself.  But you can check pretty directly that it's not! Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The ring $k[[x,y]]/(x^2 ,xy,y^2 )$  (here $k$  is a field) is not Gorenstein, because the zero ideal is not irreducible.